# Please identify this pale green weed

Tags: identification, weeds, annuals

It's an annual, growing to about 10-20 cm. It does not seem to flower, unless some of the pale green growths are petals and not leaves; but it does spread.

It is easily killed with a hoe, unless it's too close to another plant. I can't eradicate it as new plants keep appearing.

The location is England.

I have looked at lots of pictures of weeds, but found nothing like it.
[image: Weed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a petty spurge, also known as milk weed, radium weed, or cancer weed.